# using a real time clock (rtc) with Raspbian

Tags: rtc

The Raspberry Pi doesn't come with a realtime clock; if you want to run a standalone (no network) pi with the proper time automatically set on boot you need a real time clock (rtc).

There are a several rtc chips available, most run on the i2c serial bus and many are made by Dallas Semiconductor (ds1307, ds1339, ds3231).

I've wired up a ds3231 to the pi's i2c bus #1, and I can set the time on it and set the system time from the clock using the `hwclock` command.

How do I configure raspbian to do this on boot? I have removed the fake-hwclock package, but this only results in the system time being set to January 1969 on boot, which tells me `hwclock -s` was never run.

In a crude attempt to make this work, I placed the `hwclock -s` command in /etc/rc.local, but I'd like to use a more proper method.

I see there's an /etc/init.d/hwclock.sh script which is supposed to sync the system time from the rtc, but it bails if udev is configured. This implies udev should handle the sync from rtc->system clock, but it is not configured to do so.

What's the proper way to have the system time set from an rtc at boot on a raspberry pi running raspbian?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+rapberry+pi+rtc+module is where you can get the DS3231 uits for a great price.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to `/boot/config.txt` and re-boot.

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231=1
```

See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

If that doesn't work you will need to reverse any misconfiguration you did previously.

Comment: `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` has already been added to `/boot/config.txt`, and `hwclock` works as expected.

Comment: @Jason That is all you need to do.  You need to undo anything else you did.

Comment: `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` should work (it is what I use), not sure about the "=1" which is not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: OK, that worked fine. @Milliways @Joan the `=1` is not required. Thank you guys.

Comment: @joan if you'll edit your response to omit the `=1`, then I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Milliways The documentation I am using is `/boot/overlays/README` which is good but perhaps not rigorous.  `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,<param>=<val>` is perhaps ambiguous.

Comment: @joan You won't get any argument from me on the woeful state of Foundation documentation. If the people responsible were working for me they would be redoing it! I don't think anyone proof reads it.

Comment: @Milliways I wouldn't go anywhere near that far.  Certainly for my own needs I can find the information I need.  My complaints are generally nit-picks in areas with which I am very familiar.

Comment: As long as you're editing files, you might want to take a look at /etc/ntp.conf and set it to get time from a Stratum-1 source instead of the pools that are generally Stratum-16 or so.  They come installed in ubuntu and Raspbian and even Windows.  Here is how to get the real deal:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov?